# Strange behavior of registerUserNotificationSettings in iOS8

Tags: ios8, apple-push-notifications

I try to register only alert type notification at application start in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

by calling

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

In

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
```

I permanently get all types in `notificationSettings`

```
<UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x16dd6160; types: (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert UIUserNotificationTypeBadge UIUserNotificationTypeSound);>
```

And

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings]
```

gives me the same all types despite my initial choice of the only alert type.

So I can't setup restricted dynamical permissions on start.

There is no any information about similar problems in the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is impossible to setup `UserNotificationType` from application in iOS8 (at least). One needs to use general Notification Center to set any combination of sound, badge and alert. Only the first attempt to register which occurs with Push notification permissions alert sets `UserNotificationType` needed.

Another way is to send `UserNotificationType` on subscription to your push server which should make payload depending of this type.

Comment: See Update in my Answer

Answer (score 0):

You must register notifications in `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

UPDATE:
According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html):

> The first time you call the registerUserNotificationSettings: method,
>   iOS presents a dialog that asks the user for permission to present the
>   types of notifications the app registered. After the user replies, iOS
>   asynchronously calls back to the UIApplicationDelegate object with the
>   application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: method, passing a
>   UIUserNotificationType object that specifies the types of
>   notifications the user allows.
>
> Users can change their notification settings at any time using the
>   Settings app. Your app is added to the Settings app as soon as you
>   call registerUserNotificationSettings:. Users can enable or disable
>   notifications, as well as modify where and how notifications are
>   presented. Because the user can change their initial setting at any
>   time, call currentUserNotificationSettings before you do any work
>   preparing a notification for presentation

So if user has already accepted Notification settings, application can't change them. `currentUserNotificationSettings` always show current user settings, not application settings.

Comment: `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings` is just a callback called after `registerUserNotificationSettings`